# Non existence of solution of a special first kind Fredholm integral equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functional-equations, compact-operators, integral-equations

Let $k \in {L^2}((0,4) \times (0,1))$, $g \in {L^2}(0,1)$.

We consider the following first kind Fredholm equation
$$\int\limits_0^4 {k(s,x)f(s)ds=g(x), x\in(0,1).} $$
Where $f$ is the unknown. How can I prove that there exists $g$ in $L^2(0,1)$ such that the above equation doesn't  have solution. 
I thought about the compactness of Hilbert-Schmidt operator, but I think that as the kernel $k$ is not defined on a square, we cannot apply that. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Can a compact operator which is not of finite rank ever be surjective?

Comment: No, this is what I wrote. But I'm not sure about that because the kernel is not defined in a square

Comment: Does that affect the compactness of your operator in any way? (In fact, one can prove that any integral operator on $\mathscr{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$ with a square-integrable kernel over $\mathbb{R}^2$ forms a Hilbert-Schmidt operator, and is therefore compact.)

Comment: Thank you @MisterRiemann.